# How to get a Authorization token from a callback response

Tags: java, php, json

I am trying to setup a payment authorisation however I am stuck when I receive the call back as I cannot access the authotization_token

This is my code

```
$uname = 'myusrname';
    $pass = 'mypassw';
    $auth = base64_encode($uname . ":" . $pass);

$url = "https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array(
   "Authorization: Basic $auth",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = <<<DATA
{
  "purchase_country": "GB",
  "purchase_currency": "GBP",
  "locale": "en-GB",
  "order_amount": 10,
  "order_tax_amount": 0,
  "order_lines": [{
    "type": "physical",
    "reference": "19-402",
    "name": "Battery Power Pack",
    "quantity": 1,
    "unit_price": 10,
    "tax_rate": 0,
    "total_amount": 10,
    "total_tax_amount": 0
  }]
}
DATA;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
$result = json_decode($resp, true);
    $session_id = $result['session_id'];
    $client_token = $result['client_token'];
    $Payment_method_categories= $result['payment_method_categories'];
```

Then I use the `$client_token`

for the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //The following method initializes the Klarna Payments JS library
        window.klarnaAsyncCallback = function () {
            Klarna.Payments.init({ 
                client_token: '<?php echo $client_token; ?>'
            });
            console.log("Payments initialized");
    //The following method loads the payment_method_category in the container with the id of 'klarna_container'
            Klarna.Payments.load({
            container: '#klarna_container',
                payment_method_category: ''
                
            }, function (res) {
                   console.log("Load function called")
                    console.debug(res);
            });
        };
    
    
    
    /*The following is the authorize function, which triggers Klarna to perform a risk assessment of the purchase 
      The successful response of this risk assessment is an authorization token, which in this example is logged in the console
    */
      $(function(){
        $("button.authorize").on('click', function(){
            Klarna.Payments.authorize({
                payment_method_category: ''
                 
                 }, function(res) {
                    console.log("Response from the authorize call:")
                    console.log(res)
                  
                })
        })
      })
    </script>
```

Here follows the page setup:

```
<script src="https://x.klarnacdn.net/kp/lib/v1/api.js" async></script>

<div style="width: 500px; margin: auto; padding-top: 150px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
    <img src="https://x.klarnacdn.net/payment-method/assets/badges/generic/klarna.svg" style="width: 100px; margin: auto;"> 
</div>

<!--Klarna container-->
<div id="klarna_container" style="width: 500px; margin: auto;"></div>
<div style="width: 500px; margin: auto;">
    <!--Button to trigger authorize call-->
    <button class="authorize" style="width: 500px; height: 50px; margin: auto;">Continue to Klarna</button>
</div>
```

Once the data is handled by Klarna, it will send back the authorization token however I do not know how to access this, it is supposed to be a json but I have not much experience with is I understand it is in the consol.log(res) but how do I retrieve it to use in the next step? Is there a way to echo out the authorization_token? Sorry if this is very obvios however I have no idea how to get the token from this:

`Response from the authorize call:`

```
Object { show_form: true, approved: true, finalize_required: false, authorization_token: "mytoken" }
​
approved: true
​
authorization_token: "mytoken"
​
finalize_required: false
​
show_form: true
```

Any help welcome again sorry if this is very obvios

Comment: `console.log(res.authorization_token)` ? Or you can do anything else you need to with that value.

Comment: @ADyson thank you so much for your response is there a way I can print this on the page? just so I know I've retrieved it ok (Just for testing I will remove that later

Comment: Of course you can. You can use any of the standard JS DOM manipulation functions. e.g. let's say you have a `<div id="token">` on the page somewhere, you could write `document.querySelector("#token").innerText = res.authorization_token;`, something like that.